# Setting is not working in Visual Studio CMake configuration

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, visual-studio-2019

I am building Opencv with visual studio 2019 and opencv-3.4.16 source files

I selected **File->Open->Cmake** and loaded CMakeLists.txt from root of project

Once project loaded, I did right click on **CMakeLists.txt->CMake Settings for OpenCV**

I made sure I am on *x64-Release* configuration both in Visual Studio and in CMake settings.

I scrolled down and checked box **BUILD_opencv_world** as shown in image.

Saved file CMakeSettings.json, Cmake automatically re-scanned and re-loaded.

When I build the project I don't see `opencv_world.dll` or `opencv_world.lib` in the x64-Release output folder. I see all the other DLL's, which means this checkbox setting did not work

I tried doing **CMakeLists.txt->Cache->Delete**

I also tried adding `set(BUILD_opencv_world ON)` to the top of CMakeLists.txt

Nothing worked and the Opencv_world libraries are not getting built

What step am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried restarting Visual Studio? I've lost quite some time with things like these only to find out that VS wasn't updating correctly until I restarted.